# About precision and recall in prediction

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, precision-recall

I am confused about precision and recall in prediction.
My task is about object detection in an image.

If there is no object in the image, and my predict number is 1: then false positive = 1

If there is one object in the image, and my predict number is 0: then false negative = 1

However, if there is on object in the image and my predict number is 0: then what is the value of true positive? Is it 0 or 1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if there is no object in the image and my predict number is 0 then true positive = 0.